# Games such a flip a coin, rolling dice, and choosing cards

Tags: python

im trying to make a game board and i have taken some notes from my class and im just struggling to do this assignment. We never have done anything like this in class before. I need to do a coin flip, roll two dice a 6 sided one and a 20 sided one and i need to pick a card.

```
import random

def flip_coin():
    # TODO: implement this function
    # get a random int between 0 and 1
    # if the number is 0, return "Coin flip: Tails"
    # if the number is 1, return "Coin flip: Heads"
    # delete this next line:
    return 0

def roll_d6():
    # TODO: implement this function
    # get a random int between 1 and 6
    # return "D6 roll: [that number]"

    # delete this next line:
    return 0

def roll_d20():
    # TODO: implement this function
    # get a random int between 1 and 20
    # return "D20 roll: [that number]"

    # delete this next line:
    return 0

def pick_card():
    # TODO: implement this function
    # get a random number between 0 and 3
    # [card suit]: 0=spades, 1=hearts, 2=diamonds, 3=clubs
    # then get a random number between 1 and 13
    # [card value]: 1=Ace, 11=Jack, 12=Queen, 13=King, 2-10 are normal (no translation)
    # return "Your card: [card value] of [card suit]"

    # delete this next line:
    return 0


# TODO: put the following lines into a loop, to allow the user to repeat until they quit
print('Welcome to the game center!\nHere are your options:')
print('\t1) Flip a coin\n\t2) Pick a random playing card')
print('\t3) Roll a 6-sided dice\n\t4) Roll a 20-sided dice')
choice = input('What would you like to do? ')
# TODO: based on what the user selects, call the appropriate function above (print the result)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just a homework dump without any research or own attempts to do the homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are faster solutions to this: but these are the most simple solutions.

```py
import random

def coin_flip():
    generated_num = random.randint(0, 1) # generate a random number from 0 to 1

    if generated_num == 0:
       return "Coin flip: Tails"
    else:
       return "Coin flip: Heads"

def roll_d6():
    generated_num = random.randint(1, 6)
    return f"D6 roll: {generated_num}"

def roll_d20():
    generated_num = random.randint(1, 20)
    return f"D20 roll: {generated_num}"

def pick_card():
    suit = random.randint(0, 3)
    if suit == 0: suit = "Spades"
    if suit == 1: suit = "Hearts"
    if suit == 2: suit = "Diamonds"
    if suit == 3: suit = "Clubs"
    value = random.randint(1, 13)
    if value == 1: value = "Ace"
    if value == 11: value = "Jack"
    if value == 12: value = "Queen"
    if value == 13: value = "King"

    return f"Your card: {value} of {suit}"
```

### NOTE

Here is a better way to pick the suit:

```
def pick_card():
    suit = random.choice(['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs'])
    ...
```